# UICollectionViewFlowLayout Place Section Headers over Section Left Inset

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I am trying to modify `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` (vertical scroll) in order to place each section header to the left of all items of that section (as opposed to on top, which is the default).

That is, this is the default behaviour:

[image: Default Behaviour]

...and this is what I want:

[image: Desired Result]

So I subclassed `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`:

```
override func layoutAttributesForElementsInRect(rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {
    guard let attributesToReturn = super.layoutAttributesForElementsInRect(rect) else {
        return nil
    }

    // Copy to avoid the dreadded "Cached frame mismatch" runtime warning:
    var copiedAttributes = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]()

    for attribute in attributesToReturn {
        copiedAttributes.append(attribute.copy() as! UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes)
    }

    for attributes in copiedAttributes {
        if let kind = attributes.representedElementKind {
            // Non nil: It is a supplementary View

            if kind == UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader {
                // HEADER

                var frame = attributes.frame
                frame.origin.y = frame.origin.y + frame.size.height
                frame.size.width = sectionInset.left
                attributes.frame = frame     
            }
        }
        else{
            // Nil: It is an item
        }
    }
    return copiedAttributes
}
```

Also, for good measure (?), I adopted the protocol `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` and implemented this method *(although it is not clear what takes precedence. And then, there is the settings in the storyboard file, but those seem to be overriden by their runtime counterparts)*:

```
func collectionView(
    collectionView: UICollectionView,
    layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
    referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {

    let left = (collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout).sectionInset.left

    return CGSizeMake(left, 1)
}
```

...and I succeed in lowering the header to the first row of its section; However, the space originally occupied by the header stays open:

[image: Actual Result]

...and the only way I can accomplish that is by setting the header view height to `1` and "Clips Subviews" to false, so that the label is displayed (If I set the height to 0, the label is not drawn), but this is definitely **not** the most elegant solution (*and will likely break in* -say- *iOS 9.2*)

That is, the actual height of the header is **linked** to the vertical space between sections: I can not set the space to zero while keeping the header view at a reasonable size for display.

Perhaps I should also move all section items up (by the same amount as my header height) instead, to fill the hole?

Comment: did you figure this out? I'm trying to do the same thing but for a horizontal scrolling collection view

Comment: Actually, yes. I've been to busy to post the answer, but I will do today. Give me a couple of hours!

Comment: awesome! can't wait to hear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
- (NSArray<UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *> *)layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    NSArray *originalAttributes = [super layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:rect];
    NSMutableArray *allAttributes = [NSMutableArray new];
    for (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes* attributes in originalAttributes) {
        [allAttributes addObject:[attributes copy]];
    }

    for (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *attributes in allAttributes) {
         NSString *kind = attributes.representedElementKind;
         if (kind == UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader) {
            CGRect frame = attributes.frame;
            UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *cellAttrs = [super layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:attributes.indexPath];
            frame.origin.x = frame.origin.x;
            frame.size.height = self.sectionInset.top;
            frame.size.width = cellAttrs.frame.size.width;
            attributes.frame = frame;
         }
    }

    return allAttributes;
}
```

Comment: Looks like you've got the essential part of the solution right, instead of my lengthy, full-of-cruft answer. I don't have time to check if this code alone produces the expected result, but let me know. If so, you might have made my github demo project implementation a lot easier.

Comment: At first glance, it looks like you are copying the array of attributes arrays (`allAttributes`), but not the sub-arrays themselves (`attributes`); i.e. a shallow copy. Aren't you getting the runtime warning?

Comment: Your code works, I'm accepting your answer. However, I can confirm that if you do not deep copy the attributes, you get this warning at runtime (layout does not break though):

Comment: `Logging only once for UICollectionViewFlowLayout cache mismatched frame
2015-10-16 12:25:05.283 CustomFlowLayoutDemo[15159:1753244] UICollectionViewFlowLayout has cached frame mismatch for index path <NSIndexPath: 0xc000000000200016> {length = 2, path = 0 - 1} - cached value: {{386, 1}, {226, 89}}; expected value: {{486, 1}, {226, 89}}
2015-10-16 12:25:05.283 CustomFlowLayoutDemo[15159:1753244] This is likely occurring because the flow layout subclass CustomFlowLayoutDemo.LeftAlignedFlowLayout is modifying attributes returned by UICollectionViewFlowLayout without copying them`

Comment: In Objective-C, I think you should do this: `NSMutableArray *originalAttributes = [super layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:rect];
NSMutableArray *allAttributes = [NSMutableArray new];

for (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes* attributes in originalAttributes){ [allAttributes addObject:[attributes copy]]; }`

Comment: @NicolasMiari I am not getting that runtime warning. But I'm brand new to creating custom layouts, and saw this method in a tutorial. I'll give your modification a try. Makes sense to me anyway.

Comment: Mmh, perhaps it also has to do with the actual content and size of your cells... who knows.

Comment: How do i set the frames properly if i want a header at the top of horizontal scrolling collection view?

Answer (score 1):

OK, so this is what I did:

First of all, I subclassed `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` based on [this github project](https://github.com/mokagio/UICollectionViewLeftAlignedLayout), to get the left alignment I was looking for (I had to convert it from Objective-C to swift, but other than than it's pretty much the same).

Since I am already subclassing the layout object, I can implement any modifications in this subclass.

I declared a property to store the width of my "side-headers" (this quantity also doubles as the left inset of each section):

```
import UIKit

class LeftAlignedFlowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout
{
    let customHeaderWidth:CGFloat = 150.0

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {

        super.init(coder: aDecoder)        
        sectionInset.left = customHeaderWidth
    }
```

Then, in the implementation of `layoutAttributesForElementsInRect()` I did this:

```
override func layoutAttributesForElementsInRect(rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]?
{
    guard let attributesToReturn = super.layoutAttributesForElementsInRect(rect) else {
        return nil
    }

    var copiedAttributes = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]()

    for attribute in attributesToReturn {
        // Must copy attributes to avoid runtime warning:

        copiedAttributes.append(attribute.copy() as! UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes)
    }

    for attributes in copiedAttributes {

        if let kind = attributes.representedElementKind {
            // Non nil : Supplementary View

            if kind == UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader {
                // [A] HEADER

                var frame = attributes.frame

                frame.origin.y = frame.origin.y + frame.size.height

                frame.size.width = sectionInset.left
                frame.size.height = 60 // Hard-coded - header height

                attributes.frame = frame        
            }
            else if kind == UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter {
                // [B] FOOTER

                var frame = attributes.frame

                // My footer view is a "hairline" taking most of the width
                // (save for 8 points of inset margin on each side):
                frame.origin.x += 8
                frame.size.width -= 16

                attributes.frame = frame
            }
        }
        else{
            // Kind is nil : Item (cell)

            if let attributesForItem = self.layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath(attributes.indexPath){

                attributes.frame = attributesForItem.frame
            }
        }     
    }

    return copiedAttributes
}
```

There is also the implementation of `layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath()`, but that pertains more to the left alignment of the items-part, so I omitted it (if anyone is interested, please check the above-linked github project).

I will create a repository with a demo project of my implementation as soon as I have time.

These are the Size Inspector settings for the collection view and the flow layout object, respectively:

[image]
[image]

(By the way, item size is variable and determined at runtime by the delegate method, so ignore those values)

I also adopted the `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` protocol, like this:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView,
        layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
        referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize
{
    let left = (collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout).sectionInset.left

    return CGSizeMake(left, 1)
}
```

Although, to be honest, some of the layout attributes can be specified in many places (Interface Builder, properties of layout object, return value from delegate methods, etc... ) and I don't remember exactly which takes precendence in each case, so I need to clean up my code a bit.

Comment: awesome. in my case I wanted the section label above since it is a horizontal scrolling collection. so i made the label the same width as the cell at that index. see my answer below